# How do my clients submit form data (external) into my data table (internal) in Microsoft Access?

Tags: ms-access

I have developed a fully-functional two-part (front-end and back-end) Microsoft Access database for use with Microsoft Windows and wish to extend the functionality of it further so that external clients can submit their own data directly into my data tables without having to send it to me first so that I can enter it manually.

The front-end of the system exists locally for each end user (not on my LAN) and the back-end exists within my LAN.

The problem is that I have no idea how to do this and would appreciate some suggestions.

This is how I would like it to work:

```
1. Client (external / not on my LAN) enters data into form
2. Client presses "Submit"
3. Data is entered directly into my data table (internal / my LAN)
```

There are also some requirements that I need to follow:

- Clients do not have access to any existing data and cannot view it - they can only submit their own data
- Once submitted, my client cannot see or amend the data - they are presented with a blank form / confirmation screen

Also note the following:

- All users are Windows users;
- All users have Microsoft Access installed

Comment: If your clients are going to enter data into Word, then they need to purchase + install a copy of word.  If your clients are going to enter data into a Access form then what platform and software do you plan to build that form with? Do they have Access installed or are they willing to purchase + install Access? You HAVE to use something to build a form with and you not shared what tools are you are willing to learn or if it is acceptable that they will have Access installed on their computers or not. You need to clear up this issue of are users working with Access forms or not?

Comment: All users are Windows users who have access to MS Access; I have updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

To get the data inside your company network, then those desktops are going to need use of your network. When they hit submit, that data has to be sent into your existing database and that means you need to open up your network to the wild internet. Few companies (if any at all) will allow desktop programs running on peoples computers all over the country to use + open and modify files on your existing network (a dream for hackers come true!).
So while your company network could be opened up for these desktops to modify your access database, it would be a security nightmare, and impractical. It also not clear if you are able (or want to) setup these external computers to be have remote access to your company network or you talking about just nearly “any” old user of the Access database needs this ability?

If we are talking about employes that you trust, then your company network can be opened up to outside connection with a secure connection (a VPN).

If you talking about customers and general users of your application, then allowing these people to connect to and use your company network would be out of the question.

So what you are asking may be possible, but not practical from a security point of view (this is why you attempting to cook up an application that does not work like other applications that exist today). So trying to do something that no one else has accomplished tends to be a really bad idea.

Another possible solution would in place of users when hitting submit and modifying your database (on your local network), you could have their application send the data to some web site (this is how most such applications work). You thus could push up the data as XML or in some other format to the web site. You then have your desktop inside your company network download this new data several times a day. Once again this eliminates the need to open up your company network to outside connections).

Another way is that after users are done entering data, you then have Access export the data to some file and then “email” you the data file. I suppose it really depends on how frequently they will need to send you data – if frequently, then this would not be practical.

On the other hand, all of the above would likely far better accomplished by a web site and having people enter data into that web form – you then you pull that data down to your Access desktop. Of course with web based, then you have new issues like issuing logons etc, changing passwords and who will maintain those users + logons etc. However, even with these issues, some kind of web portal or site to gather the information makes far more sense than deploying Access applications to each user’s desktop for what amounts to a simple form and a submit button. A desktop database does not have the correct design and architecture for the task you are attempting to achieve.

You could also use a cloud edition of SQL server, and have Access send the data to that cloud hosted SQL server and again you then have your desktop application within your company network download that new data several times a day.

So unless you willing to introduce some additional technologies here, Access is the wrong tool for the given task